# Change document Namespace from Bundle/Document to Bundle/Model

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I'm using DoctrineMongoDBBundle, normally i put the documents into the `MyBundle/Document` directory and works fine but i want change to `MyBundle/Model`

after move my documents to new namespace i get a error message

```
[Exception] 
You do not have any mapped Doctrine MongoDB ODM documents for any of your bundles...
```

currently i'm using annotations for set the configuration, i dont want use xml or yml. this is the current config, how i can achieve this?

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: "%database_name%"
    document_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your document is `Acme/Model/Invoice`.

You can adjust the mapping like this:

```
doctrine:
  odm:
    # ...
    mappings:
      Acme:
        type: annotation
        is_bundle: false
        dir: %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Acme/Model
        prefix: Acme\Model
        alias: MyDocuments
```

Now use the the mapping like this:

```
$documentManager->getRepository('MyDocuments:Invoice');
```

If you want to keep the document inside a bundle ...

... just use the bundle's name i.e. `AcmeDemoBundle` instead of `Acme` as the mapping-name, set `is_bundle` to `true` and the `dir` option will be seen as relative to the bundle's root directory.

More information on the mapping options can be found in the documentation chapter **[DoctrineBundle Configuration#Mapping Information](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-configuration)**.

More information on *how to store documents out of bundles* can be found in **[this blog post](http://zalas.eu/how-to-store-doctrine-entities-outside-of-a-symfony-bundle/)**.

**The procedure is the same for Doctrine ORM btw.**